# Default dot behavior with no RegexOptions argument passed to Regex compiler

Tags: .net, regex

Regular expression's "^" and "$", [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference):

> `^`   By default, the match must start at the beginning of the string; in multiline mode, it must start at the beginning of the line.

And

> `$`   By default, the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string; in multiline mode, it must occur before the end of the line or before \n at the end of the line.

As such, I expected the when we specify a **Regex(pattern)**, having no **RegexOptions** parameter, will produce the same result as **Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)**.

In light of the above, can anyone explain the results of the following code:

```
var text = $"{Environment.NewLine}a{Environment.NewLine}b";

var patN = @"^.*$";
var reN = new Regex(patN);
var msN = reN.Matches(text);
Console.WriteLine($"Begin and end specified: {msN.Count}");
Console.WriteLine();

var patB = @"^.*";
var reB = new Regex(patB);
var msB = reB.Matches(text);
foreach (var mB in msB)
    Console.WriteLine($"Begin specified only   : {string.Join(" ", mB.ToString().Select(c => (int)c))}");
Console.WriteLine();

var patE = @".*$";
var reE = new Regex(patE);
var msE = reE.Matches(text);
foreach (var mE in msE)
    Console.WriteLine($"End specified only     : {string.Join(" ", mE.ToString().Select(c => (int)c))}");
```

Resulting in:

```
Begin and end specified: 0

Begin specified only   : 13

End specified only     : 98
End specified only     :
```

Character 98 is "b"

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, the differences are stated in the documentation you found. Why would you expect them to behave the same?

Comment: Ah, dang. It took me too long to write this up and now I am late to the party :(

Comment: There is no connection between the anchors and the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. You might as well remove that part of your question (the citation), it is common knowledge and is not related to the main problem.

Comment: Sebastian Proske, Victor Stribizew, Thank you. Potentially I was not clear in my question. My first WriteLine: Console.WriteLine($"Begin and end specified: {msN.Count}"); produced a value of 0 which is the mystery. I expected it to be 1. The rest of the code is exactly what I expected and I included it for clarity--though I understand that it was confusing.

Comment: @AviFarah I have edited my answer to add an explanation for that particular scenario. I didn't think I needed to explain that since it was on the link you quoted at the start of your question; before you get to the bit about anchors.

Comment: @Richardissimo, Got it.  Many thx.

Comment: @AviFarah I notice that you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. Could I suggest you take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Richardissimo, absolutely and thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is just a common misinterpretation of the regex flags m|multiline and s|singleline. Since this is common for pretty much all regex flavors I'd like to cite from [perlretut](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/perlretut):
(I've replaced `\n` with `newline` (we come to that later) and other small adjustments)

> we usually want to ignore newlines when we count and match characters
>   in a line. Sometimes, however, we want to keep track of newlines. We
>   might even want `^` and `$` to anchor at the beginning and end of
>   lines within the string, rather than just the beginning and end of the
>   string. [Most regex engines that implement these modifies allow] us to
>   choose between ignoring and paying attention to newlines by using the
>   `s` and `m` modifiers. `s` and `m` stand for single line and
>   multi-line and they determine whether a string is to be treated as one
>   continuous string, or as a set of lines. The two modifiers affect two
>   aspects of how the regexp is interpreted:
>
> 1. how the `.` character
>      class is defined, and
> 2. where the anchors `^` and `$` are able to match.
>
> Here are the four possible combinations:
>
> - no modifiers: Default behavior. `.` matches any character except `newline`. `^` matches only at the beginning of the string and `$` matches only
>     at the end or before a newline at the end.
> - s modifier `(?s)`: Treat string as a single long line. `.` matches any character, even `newline`. `^` matches only at the beginning of the
>     string and $ matches only at the end or before a newline at the end.
> - m modifier `(?m)`: Treat string as a set of multiple lines. `.` matches any character except `newline`. `^` and `$` are able to match at
>     the start or end of any line within the string.
> - both s and m modifiers `(?sm)`: Treat string as a single long line, but detect multiple lines. `.` matches any character, even `newline`. `^`
>     and `$`, however, are able to match at the start or end of any line
>     within the string.

Since the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz(v=vs.110).aspx) of new Regex(String) does not add any RegexOptions, you are certainly in the first scenario, as already mentioned.

Now to your output. The point in question here is: what is a newline for the regex engine? Does this depend on your environment (as suggested by your code) if it is Windows or something else? The [.NET documentation on anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions) is clear about that: a newline in regex is: `\n`

Citing a passage from [End of String or Line: $](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#end-of-string-or-line-):

> If you use `$` with the RegexOptions.Multiline option, the match can
>   also occur at the end of a line. Note that `$` matches `\n` but does
>   **not match** `\r\n` (the combination of carriage return and newline characters, or CR/LF). To match the CR/LF character combination,
>   include `\r?$` in the regular expression pattern. (Highlighting added)

So, since your sample code defines the input text on a Windows environment as: `\r\na\r\nb` which explains your output: `^.*` matches `\r` in the first line of the string. If you run the same code on a Linux environment you do not get a match: [Sample](https://ideone.com/ynsBQ5).

The match of the `b` running `.*$` should be obvious now. The following empty match might come to a surprise. However, since `.*` matches zero or more characters and the .NET regex `Matches()` method behaves like a global it can match again at the position after `b`.

Bonus:

If `(?m)` is being used, the start of
the string can still be matched with `\A` ([start of the string only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#start-of-string-only-a)) and the end of the string can still be matched with the anchors `\Z` ([matches both the end and
the newline before, like `$`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#end-of-string-or-before-ending-newline-z)), and `\z` ([matches only the end of the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#end-of-string-only-z)).

Comment: wp78de, Thank you.  Potentially I was not clear in my question.  My first WriteLine: Console.WriteLine($"Begin and end specified: {msN.Count}"); produced a value of 0 which is the mystery.  I expected it to be 1.  The rest of the code is exactly what I expected and I included it for clarity--though I understand that it was confusing.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of the [Regex constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Calling the Regex(String) constructor is equivalent to calling the Regex(String, RegexOptions) constructor with a value of None for the options argument.

So your expectation that the default behaviour is SingleLine is flawed.

And as explained in the [Default options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#default-options):

> The `^` and `$` language elements match the beginning and end of the input string.

And the first example returns zero because... from the [Quick language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character_classes)

> `.` Wildcard: Matches any single character except \n.

Comment: Richardissimo, Thank you. Potentially I was not clear in my question. My first WriteLine: Console.WriteLine($"Begin and end specified: {msN.Count}"); produced a value of 0 which is the mystery. I expected it to be 1. The rest of the code is exactly what I expected and I included it for clarity--though I understand that it was confusing.

Comment: @AviFarah I have edited my answer to add an explanation for that particular scenario. I didn't think I needed to explain that since it was on the link you quoted at the start of your question; before you get to the bit about anchors.

Comment: Arguably my answer already contained that information: "no modifiers: Default behavior. . matches any character except newline. ... you are certainly in the first scenario" So, no editing was required.

Comment: @wp78de Fair point; but the OP didn't "get" that from your answer, since the comment was added to your answer.

Comment: @AviFarah yea, sometimes it requires several reads till it clicks.

Comment: @wp78de, you are correct and I am sorry for being so thick headed.  I was so fixated on the ^ and $ rules and so blind to my misunderstanding of the "." qualifier that I read your respond and only saw the ^ and $ explanation, what I felt was something that makes no sense given my understanding.

I thank you for your complete answer and sorry for such slow mindedness.